# Secure DNS using Puppeteer

Tags: dns, puppeteer, chromium

Is it possible to use Chromium's Secure DNS with Puppeteer on Linux?

I can't see anything in [the docs](https://pptr.dev/), nor has using [command line arguments](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-enable-dns-over-https-doh-in-google-chrome/) helped.

Here's the code I used to try and launch the browser with secure DNS:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: [
         '--enable-features="dns-over-https<DoHTrial"',
         '-force-fieldtrials="DoHTrial/Group1"',
         '--force-fieldtrial-params="DoHTrial.Group1:server/https%3A%2F%2F%5B2606%3A4700%3A4700%3A%3A1001%5D%2Fdns-query/method/POST'
]});
```

(note that I changed the server from 1.1.1.1 to [the IPv6 equivalent](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/setting-up-1.1.1.1/linux)).

Comment: Any luck? I'm facing the issue.

Comment: Sadly I haven't discovered any solutions yet, but I'll update this question when I do!

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying the same. Silly but what I noticed immediately is that there is dash (`-`) missing in `'-force-fieldtrials="DoHT...'`

Comment: In other words it should start with two dashes?